# Настройка плагина jshintify на Windows для Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, jslint

Добрый вечер. У меня установлена nodejs и даже gulp(только не надо сейчас про grunt или webpack вспоминать, потому что вопрос не по консолькам, сегодня и все следующие дни пока вопрос не получит ответ я буду интересоваться только gui-решениями). Отвлекся, извините.

Хочу проверять js-код в легковесной программе, например http://koala-app.com/ (не IDE, они тяжеловесы). Чтобы более конкретно спрашивать берем Sublime Text. Установил плагин https://github.com/afterdesign/jshintify

Настройки у меня вызывают сомнения, обьясните пингвиноводу если с path-ами накосячил

```
{
    "debug" : true,

    "run_on_load" : true,
    "run_on_save" : true,

    "error_messages_show_count" : true,
    "error_messages_show_first" : true,

    "extensions" : [".js"],
    "jshintrc" : "C:\\Users\\t\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3\\Packages\\User\\.jshintrc",

    "show_dot" : true,
    "show_outline" : true,

    "paths" : {
        "osx" : {
            "jshint_path" : "/usr/local/bin/jshint",
            "node_path" : "/usr/local/bin/node"
        },
        "windows": {
            "jshint_path": "C:\\Users\\t\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\jshint.cmd",
            "node_path": "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe"
        },
        "linux" : {
            "jshint_path" : "/usr/bin/jshint",
            "node_path" : "/usr/bin/node"
        }
    }
}
```

Где смотреть отчеты об ошибках? Правильно ли все настроено? Есть ли легковесные решения для такой простой задачи? (Пишу на angularjs, стараюсь писать модульно, файлов много).

Comment: а так как в офф доках не пробовал сделать?

Comment: пробовал но я вижу только как немного подвисает венда, но репортов об ошибках не вижу, по этому сомневаюсь работает ли. В оффдоках есть такая строка *C:\\Documents And Settings'\IEUser\\Application Data\\npm\\jshint.cmd*, разве там не ошибка перед *IEUser*

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle в доках сомневаюсь, но поверю человеку, который гинтит в sublime

Comment: ТомашТарасович, проблема актуальна? Не воспроизводится на Windows 64-bit, Sublime Text Build 3126, плагин работает — [**демонстрация**](http://i.imgur.com/0M4KHhE.png). Установите Node.js → установите глобально `jshint` через `npm` → просто установите jshintify через Package Control, как обычно устанавливаются плагины; не проделывая манипуляций, как в инструкции на офсайте, → вообще ничего не меняйте в настройках, в Windows по-хорошему path указывать не должно. Открывайте проблемный файл → запускайте команды jshintify. Спасибо.

Comment: [**run_on_save**](https://github.com/afterdesign/jshintify/issues/5) у меня тоже не работает, разработчика об этом уведомил. Спасибо.